# Minimize calls to controller from SilverStripe template

Tags: php, silverstripe, templating

In a [Silverstripe](https://www.silverstripe.org/) application I am creating I have `NewsArticles` which have `NewsTags` (created using [silverstripe-tagfield](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-tagfield)). I am using the `NewsTags` to create a "Related News" widget in the sidebar of each `NewsArticle`. I have created a `RelatedArticles` action in the `NewsArticle` Controller and everything works perfectly.

However in order to use the `RelatedArticles` action I am forced to call the function three times. Not a huge problem but I would like to minimize the number of times I call a function that makes multiple calls to the database.

Here is a cut down version of my `RelatedNewsModule.ss` template file:

```
// First call to check if there are related articles
<% if $RelatedArticles %>

    // second call to get the array
    <% loop $RelatedArticles() %>
        ...
    <% end_loop %>

    // third call to check if there are more than one so we need navigation
    <% if $RelatedArticles.Count > 1 %>
            ... navigation markup
    <% end_if %>

<% end_if %>
```

I'd like to call the function once and maybe use properties in the SilverStripe template that would reference the two checks and the array of articles. I'm not sure how to however.

What would be the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: You don't need the brackets in the loop. And normally it should cache the query, so `if $RelatedArticles` and `loop $RelatedArticles`, at least for $has_many or $many_many relations. In your case you'll cache it manually in your action. See also https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/performance/caching#using-caches

Comment: Right oh. I'll remove the brackets and see. As per the cache the reason I asked the question was because I noticed that while debugging it a var_dump was being called 3 times.

Comment: well, you'd need to check if DB is queried three times or if it' cached. Just put ?showqueries=1 to your URL. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/debugging/url_variable_tools/#database

Comment: @rath3r Easiest way to  prevent unnecessary queries all the time would be by using partial caching with an aggregate. https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/performance/partial_caching/#aggregates that way it would do them only when an invalidation is needed.

Comment: E.g cache the expensive query to its own block check the count, or what ever value you would like to aggregate it by. I't of course does the db connection to check the values, but they are quite fast to run in sql. Getting the full data and manipulating the display is the one that causes normally the performance hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, SilverStripe should only call the database once and cache the `RelatedArticles` results for the next 2 calls.

To cache queries further we can use [Partial Caching](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/performance/partial_caching/) to cache parts of the template.

```
<% cached 'RelatedArticles', $ID, $List('RelatedArticles').max('LastEdited'), $List('RelatedArticles').count() %>
    <% if $RelatedArticles %>

        // second call to get the array
        <% loop $RelatedArticles %>
            ...
        <% end_loop %>

        // third call to check if there are more than one so we need navigation
        <% if $RelatedArticles.Count > 1 %>
            ... navigation markup
        <% end_if %>

    <% end_if %>
<% end_cached %>
```